# Is there any way to fake SAN in VMs?

Tags: vmware, san

I need to set up an SQL Server cluster for very low transaction volume functional testing.  That requires a Windows Failover cluster and according to [TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meamcs/2013/02/15/sql-2012-failover-cluster-build-step-by-step-part-1-installing-sql-2012/) and [Michael Otey](http://windowsitpro.com/windows-server-2012/windows-server-2012-building-two-node-failover-cluster) that requires a SAN.  Just to test my luck, I tried it with shared drives and the installer balks.

I'm in a VMWare environment and [Virtual SAN](https://www.vmware.com/products/virtual-san) is certainly one option but I'd rather not *buy* something for this early, low-volume test.  Googling has not turned up any open-source SAN software but maybe my search terms aren't right.  Can anyone recommend a way to support virtual failover cluster for low-volume testing?

Comment: this sounds like a question for [sf]

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try over there.

Answer (score 1):

you need shared vmdks! https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1034165

Take a look here:

https://communities.vmware.com/blogs/Abhilash_hb/2013/08/25/clustering-using-sharing-of-vmdks-between-virtual-machines

or here:

https://blogs.vmware.com/apps/2015/02/say-hello-vmotion-compatible-shared-disks-windows-clustering-vsphere.html

HTH

R\Sven